# Getting amount for current date and prior week in same table

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to get the amount for the current date and for 7 (or X) days before in the same table.

I have this PowerBI matrix (TransactionDate, Amount) and I need to sum the Amount for the row's date minus 10 days.

See example below

```
TransactionDate     Amount    Amount_TransactionDateMinus7
 01/10                 100               25     -- this is the amount for 1/3
 01/11                 150               33     -- this is the amount for 1/4
 01/12                 200               50
  ...
 01/17                 500              100     -- this ties to 1/10 date
```

To keep things simple, let's assume the data source is just a view with just those two fields.
Datasource:

```
TrxDate    Amount
1/3          20
1/3           5
...many rows
1/10         60
1/10         40
...
```

How could I calculate Amount_TransactionDateMinus7 field?  I suspect this involves working with the row context but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. The trick is to use Variables. More info and an example is in the link below but I'm quoting the relevant details.

> Variables let you access the outer filter context. Moreover, DAX
>   evaluates variables in the context of their definition, not in the one
>   where they are used.

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/variables-in-dax/

I added a new calculated column like below.

```
VAR Prev_Week_Amount =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('tbl'[Amount]),
        DATEADD('Date'[Date], -7, DAY)
    )
RETURN
    Prev_Week_Amount
```